# POST request results in "internal server error", most of the times but not all (!?)

Tags: python, flask, http-post, python-requests

EDIT:

tl;dr:

How do I post an image using python request to a flask app where I can use openCV to manipulate it?

Long version of the question and stuff I've tried out:

I am trying to POST an image from one Python Flask app to another. The problem I am facing is that it seems to work sometimes, but usually not.

App that receives the data:

```
@app.route("/post", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def post():
    print "in post"
    req = request.files['file']
    #    req = open('pug.jpg', 'r+b')
    arr = np.asarray(bytearray(req.read()), dtype=np.uint8)
    img = cv2.imdecode(arr,-1) # 'load it as it is'
    print img
    cv2.imwrite('result.png',img)
    return "Hello"
```

App that sends data:

```
def hello():
    url = 'http://IP_ADDRESS/post'
    #This image will not work
    image = open('PATH/TO/IMAGE/pug.jpg', 'r+b')
    #But with this image it will work!?
    #image = open('PATH/TO/IMAGE/res_tile.png', 'r+b')
    files = {'file': image}
    r = requests.post(url, files=files)
    image.close()
    return 'Hello World!'
```

What I have tried:

- First, I thought there were something wrong with that specific image
  but I have already tried a bunch.
- I have eliminated the POST and put it all
  in one module. Then it works.

So, there has to be something wrong in the way I am doing the POST; but it works for that other image. Really strange.

Any help would be appreciated!

EDIT:
Ive now tried a couple of additional ways, both in receiving and sending of the POST request but still no luck. Ive found more images that work and more that don't work. Puzzling and very irritating. See below for more code.

App that receives the data:

```
def post():
    print "in post"
    photo = request.files['file']
    in_memory_file = io.BytesIO()
    photo.save(in_memory_file)
    data = np.fromstring(in_memory_file.getvalue(), dtype=np.uint8)
    color_image_flag = 1
    img = cv2.imdecode(data, color_image_flag)
    print img
    cv2.imwrite('result.png',img)
    return "Hello"
```

App that sends the data:

```
def hello():
    url = 'http://IPADDRESS/post'
    image = open('../PATH/TO/IMAGE/pug2.png', 'r+b')
    files = {'file': ('hej.png', image, 'image/png')}
    r = requests.post(url, files=files, stream=True)
    image.close()
    print r.content
    return 'Hello World!'
```

Still no luck.

EDIT:

Now I've also tried "Multipartencoder" from requests_toolbelt and Im still facing the same issue. On some images it works. On others not. Does anyone out there have any idea what Im doing wrong?

App that sends request:

```
def hello():
        m = MultipartEncoder(
            fields={'field0': 'value', 'field1': 'value',
                    'field2': ('filename', open('../PATH/TO/IMG', 'rb'), 'image/png')}
        )
        print m.fields['field0']
        r = requests.post('http://192.168.0.3/post', data=m,
                  headers={'Content-Type': m.content_type})
```

App that receives the request is same as before, just changed so I access the correct field for the file (with "req = request.files['field2']")

Any tips/hits/ideas are welcome!

Comment: What is the actual error? If you're unsure, run your application in debug mode.

Comment: I don't know the actual error. I am using debug mode but since Im only posting from one app to another, I get nothing out from it. response.content just yields "Internal server error". I tried figuring this out with debug mode and therefore combined the 2 apps in to 1, thus eliminating POST...but then it works...so I really have no idea. If you have any tips on how to use debug mode when just posting to an flask app Id appreciate it.

Comment: With debug mode you'd see the stacktrace in your console (or logs depending on how you run the app).

Comment: My debug mode is on. But my console shows me nothing when this happens. Last 3 lines in my code are: 1: "if __name__ == '__main__':". 2: "app.debug = True". 3: "manager.run()"

Comment: My post simply gets a "Internal server error" response and my console is silent.

Comment: @dirn. Got any idea what this could be all about?

Comment: Without the stacktrace it's really hard to have any idea. Why are you using numpy and OpenCV just to save a file? `photo.save('result.png')` seems much simpler.

Comment: Thanks anyway @dirn. I'll be doing some image manipulation but just saving the image for now to figure out the post request. I do get a stacktrace from the images that work. Since the images that don't work also don't yield a stacktrace I am fairly confident that something is off in my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its "solved". Or rather, I found a workaround.

Both apps (both receiving and sending the image) were running locally on my machine. Pushing my receiving app to AWS and keeping my sending app on my machine seams to have solved the issue (at least from what I can see in initial tests). I wanted to have both locally to easier develop but now it seams I need to have one app running non-locally.

If any of you have any idea why this now works...Im all ears.